# Can i do this in Angular2 (child routes in child routes)

Tags: angular, routes

I'm building an application with Angular and it occurred to me that I could build an array of daughter / granddaughter routes, when implementing it, the granddaughter level did not work, my question is if this can be done and I implemented it wrong or if it is not possible to do so.

The main routes are loaded with lazy loading, then a routing ts file follows with the daughters of the main one (the first level in the example below), within that areglo of routes I wanted to put the granddaughters, but it never worked although the url didn't change, I just never got to see the grandson component.

```
const routes:Routes = [
    { 
      path: '', 
      children: [
        { 
          path:'route1', 
          component:Component1,
          children:[
            {
              path:'son-component-1',
              component:SonComponent1
            },
            {
              path:'other-son-component-1',
              component:OtherSonComponent1,
              children:[
                  {
                      path:'grandson-component-1',
                      component: GrandsonComponent1
                  },
                  {
                    path:'other-grandson-component-1',
                    component: OtherGrandsonComponent1
                  }
              ]
            },
            {
              path:'sonNComponent1',
              component:SonNComponent1
            },
          ]
         },
        { path:'', redirectTo: 'home' },
        { path:'**', redirectTo: 'home' }
      ]
  }
  ];
```

Thank you very much for your comments. Greetings.

Comment: Yes, but you need a <router-outlett></router-outlett> for each parent. So component 1 needs a route-outlet which shows soncomponent1 and othersoncomponent1, and otherSonComponent1 needs its own router-outlet to display GrandsonComponent1 and OtherGrandsonComponent1

Comment: if you want every route to be inside the same router-outlet, the routes need to be flat, not children of children. To be able to use the same parent routes eg. '/level1/level2' where you use the same 'level1' multiple times just define the route as path: 'level1/grandsoncompnent' and for the other component: path : 'level1/othergrandsoncomponent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each parent component with children needs a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the the components html file.

In the example below the ParentComponent and the Child2Component, both needs a router-outlett. Also use path: `{'', redirectTo: 'path', pathMatch: 'full'}` to automatically load the path you want the user to load, if its not specified by the url.

```
const routes: Routes = {
 { path: '', component: ParentComponent, children: [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'child1', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
   { path: 'child2', component: Child2Component, children: [
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'grandson1', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'grandson1', component: Grandson1Component },
     { path: 'grandson2', component: Grandson2Component }
   ]}
 ]
}
```

This is useful for example if the Parent component is the main page, containing a sidenav, and for the main component it shows Child1 and Child2 component. And if the Child2 component has a tab view to show different content, where the content is in each grandson component, and child 2 contains the tabs handling.

If you want each route to be related to the same router-outlet (eg. no tree in the view) you need to make the routes flat:

```
const routes: Routes = {
 { path: '', component: ParentComponent, children: [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
   { path: 'child2', redirectTo: 'child2/grandson1', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'child2/grandson1', component: Grandson1Component },
   { path: 'child2/grandson2', component: Grandson2Component },
   { path: 'child3, component: Child3Component}
 ]}
}
```

Here you only need router-outlet in the ParentComponent. This is useful if you want use the same view area for all routes.

Bonus:

```
const routes: Routes = {
 { path: '', component: ParentComponent, children: [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
   { path: 'child2', redirectTo: 'child2/grandson1', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'child2/grandson1', component: Grandson1Component },
   { path: 'child2/grandson2', component: Grandson2Component },
   { path: 'child2/:id', component: 'GrandsonWithUrlParameterComponent' }, // 'bonus'
   { path: 'child3, component: Child3Component }
 ]}
}
```

In GrandsonWithUrlParameterComponent you can show different data from your db's, specified by the url in the same component. The id can be, for example the id of a db item.

you can access what the :id is in your component by using

```
export class GrandsonWithUrlParameterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); // f.example the id of a db item
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made that (flat routes) and I already understood better how these route arrangements work, greetings!